# How to Create/Use SVN without internet to done work in Same Project without getting Crashed in iPhone Project development

Tags: iphone, ios, svn, ios4, tortoisesvn

I am using MACOS for Developing the iPhone Application.

I have made the repository in to some Public Site that gives Functionality to build the Repository in their server and after that we can use the project to work simultaneously. But it uses internet connection that's why it becomes to slow to update and modification.
I have multiple Computers and I want to Use One PC as a Server and want to Create the Repository there and after from another multiple Computer, I want to use the Same Project to be done simultaneously.

How can i done that settings or that kind repository ?
Please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will suggest you to use mercurial rather than subversion. so any one can commit locally and once the server is up, just push the changes.

SVN is a centralised and
hg is a distributed control version system

The main difference b/w 
**Subversion** uses one main directory to store the versionned version and can deploy (export) a specific revision at anytime.
whereas

**Mercurial** repository holds both the current public version and all the history. You do not have to deploy anything anywhere, just update your current repo with data from one of the revision.

and when you are using hg you do not really need to wait your server up, you can commit locally and push your changes once server up :)

To know more about look at [HERE](http://hginit.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the valuable answer.

Comment: Any time, :) i wanted to describe in details, but i thought this small summary will help you to understand easily.

Comment: if is there any other information to integrate such a local base Subversion then also tell me or give me its link.

Comment: I did not get you, could you please be more specific. :)

Comment: I mean you have given me a nice link that can be helpful to me. And i am saying that if you have more links regarding it then also give me.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using osx, chances are svn is already installed on the computer you want to use as a host. You can configure svn to work with apache and use your local machine as the svn host. The following link has the details for setting it up:

http://mark-kirby.co.uk/2008/how-to-set-up-and-use-subversion-svn-on-os-x-leopard/